# Why two transformations quite different

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rotation

I am a coder working on something related to robotics recently. This post is to know something I am not sure about the derivation of direct cosine matrix.

I have two reference materials on the hand right now, where the first one is Wiki and another is a book of robotics.
The problem confused me just comes from the definitions given by them. I found a difference in using or defining the rotation matrix, for which I give my description here.

1. Definition from Wiki, the primary reference for me
   Given $2$ cartesian coordinates, say A and B. A was assumed to be the global one or reference frame, while B is the one attached to a rigid body or the rigid body frame. Both has the same center.

$\vec{a}_i ,i=1,2,3$ represent standard base (basis) or unit vector of frame $A$ or axes $x, y$ and $z$ of $A$

$\vec{b}_j, j=1,2,3$ indicate unit vector of $B$ similarly

then the direction cosine of $\vec{b}_j $ and $\vec{a}_i$ can be obtained via

$   r_{ji} =  cos(\theta_{ji}) = \frac{\vec{b}_j \cdot \vec{a}_i}{\Vert \vec{b}_j \Vert \Vert \vec{a}_i \Vert} = {\vec{b}_j}\cdot{\vec{a}_i}$ cause$ {\Vert \vec{b}_j \Vert} =1 $ and the same to that of $\vec{a}_i $           (eq1)

We are quite sure that (eq1) is very clear.
Besides, there is
$  {\Vert}\vec{b}_j {\Vert} cos(\theta_{ji})$ which I think it is the projection of $\vec{b}_j$ on $\vec{a}_i   $

and then there should be

$   {\Vert}\vec{b}_j {\Vert} cos(\theta_{ji}) \vec{a}_i $ which I think it is the description of the unit vector of B's x-axis along $x$-axis of $A$, i.e. the $x$-component of $ B$'s $x$-component in $A$.

Similarly, it derives  $\vec{b}_1 = cos(\theta_{11}) \vec{a}_1 + cos(\theta_{12})\vec{a}_2 + cos(\theta_{13})\vec{a}_3$ meaning that the description or orientation of $x$-axis of $B$ in$ A$

Again, it gives $ \vec{b}_2$ with $ cos(2i)\vec{a}_i$ and $\vec{b}_3 $ with $ cos(3i)\vec{a}_i$

Finally, the direction cosine matrix is
$ R_{AB} = [ r_{11}, r_{12}, r_{13}; r_{21}, r_{22}, r_{23}; r_{31}, r_{32}, r_{33} ] $ which gives $B$'s orientation in $A$

By here, I have few questions that are not so sure.

1. Does this mean that frame $B$ is obtained by making a counterclockwise rotation of $\theta$ to reference frame $A$ (counterclockwise or clockwise is what I am not sure)
2. Given point $p_B$ in frame B, its coordinates in $ A $ should be $ p_A = R_{AB} p_B$. Is this correct?

---

All above is what given by myself. Later, there are also two coordinate systems in the robotics book, $A$ is reference and $B$ is rigid body frame.
The book gives the definition of

$ R^A_B =[ \vec{x}^A_B, \vec{y}^A_B, \vec{z}^A_B ] = [c_{11}, c_{12}, c_{13}; c_{21}, c_{22}, c_{23}; c_{31}, c_{32}, c_{33}]$

It also defines $R^A_B$ as the orientation of $B$ relative to $A$. The derivation is not given. It seems that each column vector of $R^A_B$ is the description of one axis or the unit vector of the axis of $B$ relative to A.

Later, what confused me is a transformation given by
$\vec{p}_A = R^A_B \vec{p}_B$
where $\vec{p}_B $ is a point coordinate in $B$ and $\vec{p}_A$ is simply its coordinate in $A$ calculated with this transformation. What I wondered is $R^A_B $ was said to be $B$'s orientation relative to $A$. The transformation hence should be
$\vec{p}_B = R^A_B \vec{p}_A$

Am I wrong?

Comment: this sounds like active versus pasive.

Comment: This might be better suited for math.SE

Comment: @physshyp Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @electronpusher  That's where I come from. Experts told me this is not a research problem.

Comment: Check active and passive coordinate transformations.

Comment: @physshyp  Am I understanding the 1st one right?